# Magento PHP Script Stops Running w/ no errors

Tags: php, html, magento

I am trying to run the following script to retrieve the items in the shopping cart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <?php echo $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
        foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
        $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
        }
    ?>

    var abc;
    abc = <?php echo $block->getAbcID()?>;
    var tag = document.querySelector("iframe");
    // Retrieving cookie with Event ID and setting Event to a variable
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + "EventID" + "=");
    var retrievedCookie = "";
    if (parts.length == 2) retrievedCookie = parts.pop().split(";").shift();
    // Insert variables into the iframe
    tag.setAttribute("src","blahblahblah");
</script>
```

When testing the page none of the html runs besides the p tags, and the following shows up under the "sources" section of the developer tools:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Can anyone explain why the php won't run?

Comment: It's running, you're just not doing anything with it. You echo the assignment of `$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();`, but all you're doing for the Id and Price is assigning them to a variable. It doesn't get sent to the screen at all.

Comment: @aynber I don't think that is correct because the rest of my javascript underneath the php won't run either. Even though the other php section still runs. I didn't include the entire script in my original question to make it easier to read, but I have added it all now.